# Proving the Optimal Strategy for a Guessing Games

Tags: probability, optimization

I thought of the following game:

- A random integer is chosen between 1 and 100 : The goal of the game is to guess the number correctly
- Player 1 will always guess the midpoint (round up) and told if their guess is smaller or bigger than the correct number. They will then re-take the midpoint until they reach the correct number.
- Player 2 first makes a random guess and is told if their guess is bigger or smaller than the number. They then divide the difference by half and makes their next guess randomly in a smaller range. They repeat this process many times until they reach the correct number.
- Player 3 guesses random numbers until they reach the correct number (Player 3 will not guess a number that they have already guessed)
- Player 4 will choose a strategy like Player 1 33% of the time,  a strategy like Player 2  33% of the time and a strategy like Player 3 33% of the time - they will adapt each strategy they pick to make sure that they will not guess a number that they have already guessed and their guess will always be in the correct search space.

As an example - suppose the number is 77

- Player 1: 50, 50 + (50/2) = 75 ... 77
- Player 2 : 65, 83, 71 ... 77
- Player 3: 54, 19, 81, 99.... 77
- Player 4 : mix(Player 1, Player 2, Player 3)

**Is there someway that we can prove which of these players has the most efficient/optimal guessing strategies? Can we mathematically prove that some of these strategies will probabilistically require fewer turns on average to reach the correct guess compared to other strategies?**

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the questions listed under Related. With high probability at least parts of your questions will have already been answered there.

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson: Thank you! I will check this out!

Comment: Any luck, Anto?

Comment: @ Gerry: Still thinking about this! Currently, I am trying to learn how to simulate these kinds of guessing strategies! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73230993/while-loops-and-midpoints